# Auto Lock Windows 10 on Hibernate

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, lock-screen, lock

Does anyone know if it is possible to auto lock your computer when you put the machine into Hibernate. I know I can lock the computer first then hibernate it but I am wondering if it is possible to do with just the Hibernate functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible.

> Right-click Desktop → *Personalize* → *Lock screen* (left pane) *Screen saver settings* (at the bottom) → *On resume, display logon screen*

Answer (score 0):

Lock Screen security works for Display off, Suspend, Hibernate, and Hybrid Sleep. One setting does it all.  Set your lock screen to lock when the above activities take place.